# How to use a partial view from a different module in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I'm trying to access a partial view in *foo* from another module *bar*. Simplified file structure:

```
application/
    modules/
        foo/
            index.phtml
        bar/
            partial.phtml
```

And in *index.html* you would have the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->partialLoop('../bar/partial.phtml', $this->paginator);
echo $this->paginator; ?>
```

The problem is that you can't actually use parent traversal, as I get this error:

```
Requested scripts may not include parent directory traversal ("../", "..\" notation)
```

Is there any way to still include the partial view into my content page? (Or am I doing it wrong?) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to pass the module argument:

```
<?php echo $this->partialLoop('partial.phtml', 'bar', $this->paginator); ?>
```

Comment: Oh, brilliant; thanks a lot. Suppose this is valid for helpers as well?

Comment: Depends on what youre trying to access and how. Take a look at the API or full documentation for the helper or component in question.

Answer (score 7):

I have gone through the same issue. 
I had to include views from one module into another module's views.
I have solved the issue by adding the script path within the controller of the view (in which I had to include the other view)

```
$this->view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/moduleName/views/scripts/actionName');
```

and then included the script within the view file:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->render('common-header.phtml');
    //Name of the file you want to include 
?>
```